# Checking if a input is inside a list of urls

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, web-crawler, data-science

I'm having some trouble trying to match user input to a list.
I would like python to grab what the user inputs for example: travel; it matches the input with first index in the list since it contains "travel". If the user types: "mystery," it would grab the second link and return true.

code example:

```py
url_links = [
    'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/travel_2/index.html', 
    'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books/mystery_3/index.html'
]

u_input = input("what genre of books do you want listed?")
```

I've tried:

1. `if any(s in url_links for s in u_input.lower()): #this gives false`
2. `if u_input.lower() in url_links: #this also gives a false.`

Thank you!

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.

Comment: @Prune what more could be added to this question? It seems pretty clear to me, I was able to answer it with all of the info provided.

Comment: Just what I posted above.  The most immediate problem is that OP leaves us to type in test data.

Comment: @Prune I didn't have to type in test data, it's clear from both of their provided `if` statements that it's not logically what they're asking. They clearly provided the use case they're looking for, showed their attempts, and explained that those attempts returned false. I can't think of anything else they could've provided that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct `if` statement you're looking for is this - it checks if the user's lowercased input is in any of the URLs in the list:

```
if any(u_input.lower() in url for url in url_links):
```

The below statement isn't doing what you want - it's checking if each character from the user input is a URL in the URLs list. This will never return true unless you have a URL that's one character long, and the user entered that same character:

```
if any(s in url_links for s in u_input.lower()):
```

This statement is also incorrect because it's checking if the user's whole input is a URL, not if it's within a URL:

```
if u_input.lower() in url_links:
```

Answer (score 2):

So there is a little mistake in your first example.
You need to check that your links list elements contains your input string, and here

```
if any(s in url_links for s in u_input.lower()): #this gives false
```

you are doing the opposite thing. You are checking that your input string characters persists in your links list.

Here is the right way to do it:

```
 if any(u_input.lower() in link for link in url_links):
```

But really, I think that, that is not the right way to do your task.
Because if I would pass 'a' as an input instead of 'mystery' it would be True for the above condition. I suggest you to parse your links and extract the nessesarry part from it (you can use [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) for it).